# Openpyxl: Solutions for Slow Inserting New Column

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Thanks in advance.
I'm trying to add a blank column to the front of a spreadsheet. This spreadsheet can have any number of columns and rows, but I'm currently testing on a spreadsheet with 97 columns and 100 rows.

I cannot find a solution that takes less than a minute, despite being able to do this in Excel in under a second.

All information suggests using:

```
ws.insert_cols(1)
```

But this is very slow...

Does anyone know of a better way to do this?
Many thanks!

Edit - thanks for answers so far, but I can't use a different package. The rest of the program works in openpyxl, so I'd effectively double my loading times by using a new package too.

Comment: Have you tried doing it with Xlwings then?

Comment: What does your code actually do? Does it use `addrow`? Does it set one cell at a time?

Comment: On the other hand, Python is an interpreted language while Excel isn't just a native application. It *already* contains all the relevant data and structures in memory. When you click on `Save`, Excel will store those structures to an `xlsx` file. `openpyxl` has to create those structures before saving them

Comment: You could try using openpyxl's [write-only mode](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/optimized.html#write-only-mode) to speed up writes

Comment: I find it hard to believe that the single call takes so long to run. Openpyxl does have to reassign 9700 but that should take a couple of seconds at most.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos your suggestions are, unfortunately, either incorrect or irrelevant.

Comment: @CharlieClark you mean asking for the real code is incorrect or irrelevant? That there's no Write mode explicitly for performance reasons? That Excel doesn't keep the data in memory? That Python isn't slower than native compiled applications, meaning the work done for 3.10 and later is meaningless?

Comment: I mean: openpyxl doesn't have an `addrow` method; Excel does **not** store the data internally in the same way as in XML; performance comparisons are not that related to Python being interpreted (it's memory allocation above anything else); write-only mode **isn't** suitable for someone wanting to edit a workbook.

Answer (score -1):

Please use Pandas Library.
If you're not already using it, consider leveraging the Pandas library for working with spreadsheets in Python.
Pandas provides a high-level data manipulation interface that can handle large datasets more efficiently.
You can read your spreadsheet into a Pandas DataFrame, insert a blank column at the desired position, and then export the DataFrame back to a spreadsheet format.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('example.xlsx')

df['new column'] = ['insert code']

df.to_excel('example.xlsx', index=False)
```

Comment: Thanks for this Hudson! I should have explained in my request that I wouldn't want to load the data into another package, since I'm already using openpyxl elsewhere. This would harm the speed.

Comment: Pandas uses `openpyxl` as well but probably uses a more efficient way. We can't guess without any code

Comment: This will always be slower: the file has to be loaded into openpyxl then into Pandas then back into openpyxl and then back to XLSX.